# Solve the recurrence $T(n) = 5T(n/5) + n/\log(n)$

Tags: recurrence-relations

> $T(n) = 5T(n/5) + n/\log(n)$

I tried everything but I can't solve this recurrence.

I would love to know a way using the masters theorem.

Comment: Welcome to MSE, Jurko. By Master's theorem, do you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms) ?

Comment: Your example is one of the inadmissible recurrences in the Wikipedia article on Master theorem. Try using [Akra-Bazzi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs in https://cs.stackexchange.com/ (they need to add a few more sites of the SE network in the migration part of closing)

Comment: Is there a solution for this? I'm having difficulties with this one as well. Tried Akra-Bazzi and stuck on the integral which I do not know how to evaluate

Answer (score 1):

Making $n = 5^m$ and substituting we have

$$
T(5^m) = 5 T(5^{m-1})+ \frac 1m 5^m
$$

or equivalently

$$
R(m) = 5 R(m-1) +\frac 1m 5^m
$$

The homogeneous has as solution $R_h(m) = c_0 5^m$ making a particular with structure $R_p(m) = c_0(m)5^m$ and substituting into the complete recurrence we get

$$
c_0(m) = c_0(m-1) - \frac 1m
$$

with particular solution

$$
c_0(m) = \sum_{k=1}^m \frac 1k = H_m
$$

hence

$$
R(m) = (c_0+H_m)5^m
$$

and going backwards with $m=\log_5 n$ we have

$$
T(m) = (c_0+H_{\log_5 n})5^{\log_5 n} = (c_0+H_{\log_5 n})n
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$T(n) = 5T(n/5) + n/\log(n) = 5(5T(n/25) + (n/5)/(\log (n/5))) +n/\log n$

$= 5T(n/25) +n/\log (n/5) +n/\log (n) = \cdots= 5^iT(n/5^i) +\sum_{j=1}^{i−1} n/\log (n/5^j).$

When $i= \log_5n$ the first term reduces to $5^{\log_5n}T(1)$.

Comment: The problem with this hint is that it's really the second term that's the challenge.

Comment: i have solved the full problem....but here I gave the initial works..